# regex to remove certain parameters from urls

Tags: php, regex, parameters

Hello I have a query which i need to remove from the url

It looks like `&h=blablabla` (where blablabla can be anything

How do you use regex (or any other method) for the above?

I tried `&h=*` which is not working

Comment: Can you clarify? What does the url look like and what are you trying to do? Show an example or two of what you are trying to do.

Comment: http://www.example.org/about-all-of-us&h=blablabla or  http://www.example.org/about-all-of-us&h=lalala. I just need http://www.example.org/about-all-of-us and trying to remove &h=blablabla & &h=lalala.

Comment: Why use a regexp? Use `parse_str` to parse it into an array, remove the parameter, and then use `http_build_query` to put it back together.

Comment: found it /&h\=.*$/ - Thanks to all for the help and advise

Answer (score 0):

From your question I can't really tell what you are trying to do, but maybe this will help:

```
$url = "example.org/about-all-of-us&h=blablabla&j=parameter&k=moreparam";

$split_url = explode('&', $url);

print_r($split_url);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => example.org/about-all-of-us
    [1] => h=blablabla
    [2] => j=parameter
    [3] => k=moreparam
)
```

Or, if you just need `example.org/about-all-of-us`, then do this:

```
$url = "example.org/about-all-of-us&h=blablabla&j=parameter&k=moreparam";

$url = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, '&'));

echo $url; //example.org/about-all-of-us
```

Comment: Thanks Will explain more.. I have a plugin which removes parameters like &h=blablabla and &h=lalala if only you specify the exact match. The &h= keeps changing as its dynamic. Was thinking there could be a regex for the same.

Comment: @HelenM I still am not really understanding. The second example in my answer will remove *any and all* parameters, regardless of what they are.

Comment: so if i only want to remove the param (all &h=), will this work? $url = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, '&h=*'));

Comment: @HelenM It will remove everything starting at the `&`. Look at the 2nd example, `example.org/about-all-of-us&h=blablabla&j=parameter&k=moreparam` will become `example.org/about-all-of-us`